# Why can't itext read this tiff

Tags: clojure, itext

I am using iText `7.0.0` to read in pages from a TIFF image file and add those pages to a PDF.

I have found an example TIFF that iText cannot read.

The answerer of this question [Exception when converting tiff file to pdf file with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787388/exception-when-converting-tiff-file-to-pdf-file-with-itext) mentioned sharing problem TIFFs, so I am doing that here.

This is a clojure example that fails reading the first page with both the `recoverFromImageError` and `direct` flags set to true.  It also fails to read all of the other pages.

```
(let [tiff "test-multi-rgb-compression-type-7.tiff"
      url (UrlUtil/toURL tiff)]
    (Image. (ImageDataFactory/createTiff url true 1 true)))
```

This produces the following stacktrace:

```
com.itextpdf.io.IOException cannot.read.tiff.image
  TiffImageHelper.java:  279  com.itextpdf.io.image.TiffImageHelper/processTiffImage
  TiffImageHelper.java:   89  com.itextpdf.io.image.TiffImageHelper/processImage
  ImageDataFactory.java:  400  com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory/createTiff
```

The TIFF file is accessible here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5HypmT13gm-RGFURWZ4SlgxLUk/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for you time.

Comment: I don't know a lot about the TIFF format but after stepping through the code I see [this is where](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/TiffImageHelper.java#L427) the true exception starts from

Comment: Well if that's where it's originating, it looks like this might still be the case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754513/how-to-fix-compression-jpeg-is-only-supported-with-a-single-strip-issue

Comment: Caleb's guess about the cause is probably right. The file contains JPEG-compressed pages inside the TIFF file. Also, these pages use the 'new' JPEG compression (type 7), which not all viewers support.
For a good technical discussion, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733867). For a short discussion of TIFF sub-types and some additional sample files, See [this post](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/?topicid=10960). **Disclaimer**: I work for the company that owns this website.